# Multiple modal js + php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've flexible content based on wordpress page which gives our client opportunities to configure pop-ups in specific page by himselfs.

So the problem is that on one page we've quite a few, let's say infinity numbers of rows of content.

Every specific row has a unique ID created by counting "$i++;".

I'm trying to create a script which will give me the possibility to create unique pop-ups for unique flexible content automatically, based on numbers of current rows.

Here is PHP code

```
<div class="row">
    <?php if( have_rows('service_component') ): $i = 0; ?>
        <?php while( have_rows('service_component') ): the_row(); $i++; ?>
            <div class="six columns">
                <img onclick="openRightMenu()" src="<?php the_sub_field("feature_image"); ?>"> 
                <h3><?php the_sub_field("title"); ?></h3>
                <div class="servicesHidden sidenav" id="right_slider_<?php echo $i; ?>">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeRightMenu()">&times;</a>
                    <?php the_sub_field("services"); ?> 
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Code above works correctly: content is generated and every div is unique:

```
<div class="servicesHidden sidenav" id="right_slider_<?php echo $i; ?>">
```

So next step is to create javascript. Code below also works properly, but only on one unique ID.

```
<script>
    function openRightMenu() {
    document.getElementById("right_slider_1").style.width = "33%";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "33%";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    }

    function closeRightMenu() {
    document.getElementById("right_slider_1").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginRight = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
</script>
```

**Question is: how to modify function above to to let it display and hide unique content endlessly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the id into the function

```
function openRightMenu(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.width = "33%";
   ...
}
```

And in your html

```
<img onclick="openRightMenu('right_slider_<?php echo $i; ?>')" src="<?php the_sub_field("feature_image"); ?>">
```